# Can we group same objects by different fields in java?

Tags: java

I want to group a single list into list of lists using conditional comparison between different field of the same object.

For Example: Say we have below class in java

```
class Flight {
   String departureStation;
   String arrivalStation;
}
```

Now I have `List<Flight>` and I want them to group in `List<List<Flight>>` if flight say, `f1.arrivalStation == f2.departureStation` into one list.

for example, say we have `Flight f1 = {departureStation = "Hyderabad", arrivalStation = "Mumbai"}`, `Flight f2 = {departureStation = "Mumbai", arrivalStation = "Delhi"}` and `Flight f3 = {departureStation = "Dubai", arrivalStation = "Newyork"}` then the final list should looks like,
since `(f1.arrivalStation == f2.departureStation)` these two should get into one `List` and for `f3` since there is no match with given condition it'll be inside `List` alone. and while grouping we should get `List<List<Flight>>` with length of `2` , in which the first `List` should have contained `f1 and f2` and other list should contain  `only f3`

Comment: you would need to define better, what kind of grouping is this? got some sample data to explain?

Answer (score 2):

I would create a stream out of `List<Flight>` and use `.filter()` to eventually collect it as a list. Then, you can do whatever you want to do with this list.

For the examples, we consider `flights` to be of the type `List<Flight`.

```
List<Flight> filteredFlights = flights.stream()
        .filter(f -> f.arrivalStation.equals("Singapore"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This can then be added to a new `List` which forms a list of lists.

```
List<List<Flight>> listOfLists = new ArrayList();
listOfLists.add(filteredFlights);
```

However, your example condition is slightly more complex and needs a loop within a loop which has a quadratic complexity of O(n²) with n as the number of flights in the list. You can choose between different loops, I combine the classical `for` loop with the suggested stream solution (see above).

```
for(Flight f1 : flights) {
    List<Flight> temporaryList = flights.stream()
           .filter(f2 -> f1.arrivalStation.equals(f2.departureStation))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
    listOfLists.add(temporaryList);
}
```

With some dynamic programming, the efficiency can be slightly improved.

(I ignored the missing getters and setters. For proper encapsulation, you might want to add them.)

Answer (score 0):

Sample implementation could be as follows:

- collect list elements to a map: key - the list element, value - list of flights meeting the condition (self element or the element with departure equal to arrival)
- retrieve collection of values and filter it
- print the results

```java
List<Flight> data = Arrays.asList(
        new Flight("MOS", "MAD"), 
        new Flight("MAD", "BOS"), 
        new Flight("MAD", "JFK"), 
        new Flight("JFK", "MOS")
);

data.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, 
                              x -> data.stream()
                                       .filter(y -> x.equals(y) || y.dep().equals(x.arr()))
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList())))
                       .values()
                       .stream()
                       .filter(e -> e.size() > 1)
                       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

output:

```
[MAD -> JFK, JFK -> MOS]
[MOS -> MAD, JFK -> MOS]
[MOS -> MAD, MAD -> BOS, MAD -> JFK]
```

Or a set of all airports may be retrieved and then the flight data could be selected by an airport - if it's mentioned as a departure or arrival:

```java
data.stream()
    .flatMap(x -> Stream.of(x.dep(), x.arr()))
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, 
                              x -> data.stream()
                                       .filter(y -> y.dep().equals(x) 
                                                 || y.arr().equals(x))
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    )
    .values()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.size() > 1)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

output

```
[MOS -> MAD, JFK -> MOS]
[MOS -> MAD, MAD -> BOS, MAD -> JFK]
[MAD -> JFK, JFK -> MOS]
```